# Systematic way of creating the complement of a regular grammar?

Tags: computational-complexity, computability, regular-language

Regular languages are *closed under complement*. And any regular language can be generated using a regular grammar. Is there a systematic way to create the rewrite rules for the complement of a regular language?

Example: Below are some rewrite rules that generate this regular language: zero or more x's followed by zero or more y's:

> S → xS | yA | ε 
>   A → yA | ε

Note: ε is the empty string.

The complement of that regular language is this regular language: all strings containing at least one occurrence of yx (i.e., y before x).

I figured out some rewrite rules which generate that complement language:

> T → yB | yT | xT 
>   B → xT | xC 
>   C → ε

But I had to figure out those rewrite rules from scratch. I didn't reuse the other rewrite rules. Intuitively, it seems like the rewrite rules for a complement language should reuse the rewrite rules of the non-complement language. But how?

Comment: Is there a computer science SE where you may be more likely to get an answer to this?

Comment: This is just a random suggestion: if you know how to move between the grammar and a DFA for the language, then you can use that, since expressing the complement of a language is easy to find using a given DFA.

Comment: @Zach: Write that as an answer.

Comment: @Stephen: Such questions are commonly answered here.